# .Length behavior vs .LongLength when array size is larger than Int32.MaxValue

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm looking for some documentation on the differences between an array's .Length and .LongLength properties.

Specifically, if the array's length is larger than Int32.MaxValue, will .Length throw an exception, return Int32.MaxValue, go negative, return 0?

(to clear up "possible duplicate" concerns: I'm not asking about the maximum length of an array, or the maximum size of a .NET CLR object. Assume a 64 bit system and a CLR version which supports large objects)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Agreed, and good point. The lack of documentation just disturbs me, and I'd like to write something which is correct according to spec.

Comment: OP I suggest removing the performance bit from your question, people will focus on it instead of on your actual question.

Comment: Why did not just try it?

Comment: Both properties operate in O(1) according to the documentation, but I agree with Henk that the docs are unclear on your other questions. Since you've also clarified your question, I've retracted my close vote and removed previous comments.

Comment: is it even possible?
 an int array with of size int32.maxvalue will require 8GB data. this amount is way too large to achieve. For any practical purpose, you will never allocate such absurd amount of memory. IMO, for this reason, the docs have made no comments about such behaviour

Comment: It is not possible to create an array having more than 2,147,483,591 elements, so we will never know (will we ever?) what would be if we could create an array having more than `Int32.MaxValue` elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to create a one dimensional array having more than 2,147,483,591 elements (for comparison, `int.MaxValue` is 2,147,483,647). `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown if an attempt is made to create an array with more elements. It means that the `LongLength` property is *still* useless and you can **use the `Length` property instead**.

I've tested it on the x64 platform using .NET 4.5. In order to create the array with 2,147,483,591 elements I've modified the configuration file and added:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Basically, I used this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) to enable arrays that are greater than 2 (GB) in total size. The real limit for arrays:

> The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591
>   (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and
>   2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.

Comment: There have to exist additional restrictions than just the single dimension limit: I can create a 6 GB 2-dim array of shorts `new short[24, 134217728]` (or larger structs) but not of bytes: `new byte[96, 67108864]`.